# Tensorflow transfer learning sample size

Tags: tensorflow, sample-size

I want to do transfer learning on pretrained image classification model for just two classes, whether event A occurred or not. I know the retraining itself is very efficient. What about the sample size? What's the minimum sample size I can use for meaningful results?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example is helpful, ignore the characters you can't understand, they are Chinese.
[transfer learning](https://github.com/caicloud/tensorflow-tutorial/blob/master/Deep_Learning_with_TensorFlow/1.0.0/Chapter06/2.%20%E8%BF%81%E7%A7%BB%E5%AD%A6%E4%B9%A0.ipynb)